# How does the mail icon count number show up on the iPad / iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, badge

I want to use the same number count like the mail icon for the iPhone and iPad how does that small number pop up over an icon?

Answer (score 6):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 3;
```

Remember to set this to 0 when you want the badge to go away, so it doesn't get stuck there annoyingly.